# Problem in make for qt_create(ed) package

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to follow this tutorial link:[here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates)

After creating the qt package by running this line:

> rosrun qt_create roscreate-qt-pkg qdude

And after I run the make:

> make

I got this error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (QT4_ADD_RESOURCES):
> Unknown CMake command "QT4_ADD_RESOURCES".

Did I miss something. For your information, I have installed Qt Creator IDE, which mean, the Qt library is in my system, right?

I am quite new in Ubuntu and I apologise if this question is redundant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33191/problem-in-make-for-qt_create(ed)-package/) by [khinhooi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2303/khinhooi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although the OP is kind of old, and `qt_creator` is deprecated from `fuerte`, just trying to answer for the record (esp. there seem not an alternative as of today).

Not entirely sure but 1st of all, have you added the path of your package to `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`? Also, is `Qt` really installed? What does the following command return?

```
$ rospack find %YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME%
$ qmake --version
```

If something in the result looks wrong, fix it first.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0